# Formsflow.ai - form file upload recommendation

Tags: camunda, formsflow.ai

We are using formsflow to create the forms but we dont sure what is the best solution to implement the file upload option into the forms and how we can send/store theses files.

do you have some recommendation?

Regards.

I expect good recommendations in order to build the best solution

Answer (score 1):

formsflow.ai uses form.io for form design. You may use the default base64 document upload, or create a custom component for document management.

Please create a discussion [here](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/discussions) to discuss directly with maintainers.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't "slow" to responses; don't recommend posting elsewhere for a faster response. More or less recommend that it's a better-suited platform where the maintainers will respond.